# Appending data between Google sheet tabs using GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to append some data from one tab in a Google Sheet to another. Once the data has been appended, I want to update a column called 'Appended' and set it to 'Yes'. My code should then skip any lines that have already been appended, however I'm a beginner, so this is all a bit new to me.

```
function dumpSMSintoSender() {
    var MOVED_TO_SENDER = "Yes";
    var userSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var userTab = userSheet.getSheetByName('SmartCare');
    var SenderTab = userSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var numRows = 200
    var firstRow = 2;
    var range = userTab.getRange(firstRow, 3, userTab.getLastRow() - firstRow +1, 3);
    var data = range.getValues();
    var dataRange = userTab.getRange(firstRow, 3, numRows, 10)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var Movedata = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < Movedata.length; ++i) {
        var row = Movedata[i];
        var MovedtoSender = row[5];
        var sender = row[0];
        var mobile = row[1];
        var message = row[2];
        if (mobile != "") {
            if (MovedtoSender != MOVED_TO_SENDER) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
                SenderTab.getRange(SenderTab.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length,3).setValues(data);
                userTab.getRange(firstRow + i, 8).setValue("Yes");
                // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
                SpreadsheetApp.flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is actually happening, is for every loop through the code, it is appended everything from the sheet. So if there are 5 records to be appended, 25 new records will appear in the new tab because each recorded has appended 5 times (Once for every iteration). Can the code be changed to only append rows where the 'Appended' column is null?

Comment: Hello Evision and welcome to StackOverflow. From what I could gather from your question, you seem new to programming. That's okay, we all started somewhere. In the future, please take a look at [code indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style). It helps organize the code visually and makes it easier to read for anyone trying to help you. Most programming tools available even have this as built-in functionality. Please use it in the future when posting code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep it simple and the two items to check - mobile (`MOBILE_COL`) and moved to sender (`MOVED_TO_SENDER_COL`), out of the loop. They are defined up top to accomodate any future change, like `MOVED_TO_SENDER`.

Then getting `userTab` whole sheet range and values. And comparing the values as per shown in above code, row by row, to seek for new row that is not appended before.

When a new row is found, add it to `results` array and update this current row appended value to 'Yes'. Once we have all the new rows into `results` array, we write them into `senderTab`. And update `userTab` with updated `userValues`.

The trick here is to accumulate all the new rows and write them together at one go. It is faster than writing row by row. Same method applied when updating `userTab`. We update the `userValues` which is in memory and write the whole array at last in one go to `userTab`.

```
function dumpSMSintoSender() {
  // value to check for
  var MOVED_TO_SENDER = 'Yes';
  // which column is mobile, which is first item to test
  var MOBILE_COL = 4; // A = 1, B = 2 etc
  // which column is move to sender = appended, which is second item to test
  var MOVED_TO_SENDER_COL = 8; // A = 1, B = 2 etc

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var userTab = ss.getSheetByName('SmartCare');
  var senderTab = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // getting userTab full sheet range and values
  var userRange = userTab.getDataRange();
  var userValues = userRange.getValues();

  // array to keep new append-able rows
  var results = [];

  // for each row in userValues check to see if append-able
  // if yes, add to results array and update userValues array by setting appended to 'Yes'
  userValues.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row[MOBILE_COL - 1] != '') {
      if (row[MOVED_TO_SENDER_COL - 1] != MOVED_TO_SENDER) {
        results.push(row);
        row[MOVED_TO_SENDER_COL - 1] = MOVED_TO_SENDER;
      }
    }
  });

  // write new rows to senderTab
  senderTab
    .getRange(senderTab.getLastRow() + 1, 1, results.length, results[0].length)
    .setValues(results);
  // update userTab
  userRange.setValues(userValues);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems to work well, I just need to ask how to make one change. Currently, this appends all the columns to the new sheet. Could you please show me how to modify this to only append Columns 2,3 & 4? (C,D & E) for example. All the other functionality is perfect!

Comment: `results.push([ row[2], row[3], row[4] ]);` changing into this. and col C = 3, not 2

Comment: Everything is working well, I have only one issue remaining... The tab with the data which is being moved, contains a lot of formulas. However every time the script runs, it removes all the formulas leaving only the values. Is there anyway I can change that?